# Why when i use canvg ie throw exception Security error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, canvg

I have this code,but when i try to use canvas.toDataUrl i have exception "Security error" in ie 11,how i can resolve this problem?

```
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");//get svg
var img = document.createElement("img");//create img
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");//create canvas

var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();//get bounds
canvas.width = svgSize.width * 3;
canvas.height = svgSize.height * 3;
canvas.style.width = svgSize.width;
canvas.style.height = svgSize.height;

var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

var svg64 = btoa(svgData);
var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
var image64 = b64Start + svg64;

img.onload = function () {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.scale(3, 3);
    var x0 = Math.floor(0);
    var y0 = Math.floor(0);
    ctx.translate(-x0, -y0);           
    var bg = graph.background;
    //set background
    if (bg == null || bg == '' || bg == mxConstants.NONE) {
        bg = '#ffffff';
    }

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = bg;
    ctx.fillRect(x0, y0, Math.ceil(svgSize.width * 3)Math.ceil(svgSize.height * 3));
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);//try to get url for image
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "download_img" + ".png";
    a.href = canvasdata;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    //download my image
    a.click();
};
img.src = image64;//set src
```

It is work fine  in Chrome,but in ie i have some problem ,please help me.

**UPDATE**

if i use canvg , toDataUrl return blank image
 this my changed code

```
            var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

            var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
            canvas.width = svgSize.width * 3;
            canvas.height = svgSize.height * 3;
            canvas.style.width = svgSize.width;
            canvas.style.height = svgSize.height;
            svg.width = svg.parentNode.width;
            svg.height = svg.parentNode.height;
            var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);   
            canvg(canvas, svgData.trim());
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var data = atob(dataURL.substring('data:image/png;base64,'.length)),
                asArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);

            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
                asArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var blob = new Blob([asArray.buffer], { type: 'image/png' });
            saveAs(blob, 'export_' + Date.now() + '.png');
```

I have this [svg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QzlU37czVffifMutGuxV2sAnvrbY_ZIw) on the page

Also i have only svg.
As result i want to save this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw5tM.png)

Comment: you are not using canvg here...

Comment: @Kaiido I added my code with canvg,but it also didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use [canvas.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) directly? (can be polyfilled). What's in your svg? What does "didn't work" mean? Do you have anything drawn on the canvas?

Comment: @Kaiido I added my svg file,"didn't work mean than as result i have blank image but i need to save my svg file from page as png to computer",Unfortunately canvas is empty

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/2ynwdhjz/) on a VM.

Comment: @Kaiido I' m sorry,i replace svg file what i need and it doesn't wok

Comment: this svg contains links to external files. You need to embed them in your svg (as dataURI for binary files) and then canvg will be async, so you'll have to wait for its ?onload? callback

Comment: @Kaiido I tried to use onload ,but in ie i had exception security error as in first situation

Comment: @Kaiido I've changed link in svg file(you can see it references in question) but result also is blank image